# How to map start_lsn in sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions to __$start_lsn in a CDC table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc

If you look at the start_lsn in the sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions the format is '000127D3:00003C95:0001', how would you map this to an actual lsn in a Change table, the change table __$start_lsn looks like 0x000127D500003D310001, is there a known method to map this start_lsn to __$start_lsn?

Comment: Check http://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/day11of31daysofdisasterconvertinglsnformats. But *why* do you want to do that?

Comment: To periodically check if the capture instance has new entries, if it does, what are the changes that are corresponding to that

Comment: Hmm… I'm not saying that's the wrong way to do it, but I haven't seen it used that way. What I *have* seen is either you ask for some certain range of changes (e.g. "what changes happened in the last 25 hours?") or, if you need more precision, you keep track of LSN ranges you've processed and get changes that way. But asking for changes and getting none back isn't an error. The cdc_log_scan_sessions DMV is more for monitoring.

Comment: I am using multiple wokers to query the same CDC table and this is based on the LSN to make sure they don't read the same change sets @BenThul

Comment: @BenThul do you know where I could find documentation about the formats for LSN on msdn website? any particular reason lsn in the log scan sessions is in a format like '000127D3:00003C95:0001'

Comment: Not "official", but this guy is top notch: http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/

Comment: Akash, Not certain what your end result is here. Is this a simple case of determining the latest LSN for each instance to check for additional data in the CT tables?